# how do I navigate and grab infos from an Array like this

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

Im trying to navigate and fetch info from this array but im not having much success any tips? This is an decoded JSON from Twitter API

I tryed `echo $array->statuses[0]->created_at;` and it did not work, am i doing something wrong here?

```
Array
    (
        [statuses] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [created_at] => Thu Jul 06 04:05:06 +0000 2017
                        [id] => 882812623959584768
                        [id_str] => 882812623959584768
                        [text] => RT @blackdragonsBR: [R6] GG!! Fechamos o mapa Banco por 5x2 e conquistamos a liderança no #ALIENWARENOIGN #GOBD #Acer #Predator https://t.c…
                        [truncated] => 
                        [entities] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [hashtags] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [text] => ALIENWARENOIGN
                                                [indices] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => 90
                                                        [1] => 105
                                                }

                                        )
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Well i think i figured it out, `echo $array['statuses'][0]->created_at;`

Comment: Just use `[]` at the first access like: `$array[statuses][0]->created_at;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the array by `[]` not `->`. So change the access of statuses like below

```
$array[statuses][0]->created_at;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **json_encode** and **json_decode** at time then it make the variable to array only then you can get the data easily.
Just like this

```
$array=json_decode(json_encode($array,true),true);
$array[statuses][0]['created_at'];
```

It will work for you